# Search through an php array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this one.

```
$array = Array(
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Eve Greenhaw
                [id] => 456564765
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => Tyrone Hallberg
                [id] => 5467652534
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [name] => Julio Torbert
                [id] => 254564564
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [name] => John Torbert
                [id] => 5462253455
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [name] => John Kimmell
                [id] => 4525462
            )

    )
```

I want to search through the array and return the name and id. For example if the user searches for 'John', I wants the function to return keys 3, and 4. If the user searches for just 'J', the function should return keys 2,3 and 4.

Thanks

Comment: Search this page for the word recursive.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "return keys" - do you want the relevant array entries returned (i.e.: the return is an array containing the matching arrays) or just the numeric keys of the original array?  In terms of the search, on what basis should it operate? Should it be a direct match from the beginning of the string, or just match elements that contain the provided characters?

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'm trying to match the elements that cantain the provided characters. I've tried using array_search but only get it to work by searching the full name and doesnt work if the user just searches part of the name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility is [`array_filter`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

> **array_filter**(array *$input*, callback *$callback*)
>
> Iterates over each value in the *input* array passing them to the *callback* function. If the callback function returns true, the current value from input is returned into the result array. Array keys are preserved.

Each member of `$array` is itself an array, so you could do something like this (assuming you were searching both the name and the id):

```
$query = 'whatever';

function single_search($member) {
    global $query;

    $in_name = strpos($member['name'], $query);
    $in_id = strpos($member['id'], $query);

    return is_numeric($in_name) || is_numeric($in_id);
}

$filtered = array_filter($array, 'single_search');
```

The `$filtered` array contains all the name/id pairs that contained your query. But if you're only interested in the *keys*, you can use one more function: [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php). It can return an array of the keys in `$filtered`, which would be all the keys that matched the query etc etc etc:

```
$matched_keys = array_keys($filtered);
```

Good luck.

Comment: And now that I posted that, Gazler's comment about using [`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) is way sexier. :/

Answer (score 1):

Iterate the $array in foreach() and use stripo()s or preg_match() to find the matching records and return the keys. Very simple.